# How to add Title attribute to Menu links?

Tags: routes, navigation

Is it possible to add Title attribute to Menu items? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just enter text in the description field and it will be rendered as the link title.

Comment: Sometimes, something that seems to be damn difficult is solved very easily...Thanks.